# Aerospike, NodeJs module, abstracting client

Tags: node.js, aerospike

I'm struggling with aerospike nodejs module, what I would like to achieve is the following:

```
asdAbstractedModule.update(config, [foo, bar, ...]);
```

The idea behind this is to update foo, bar, etc. with a now() timestamp.
But the way aerospike client works makes this kinda difficult or maybe not really straight forward. This is what I got so far:

```
const aerospike = require("aerospike");
const config = require("./config");

let errors = 0;
let invalid = [];
let client;

let app = {};

app.update = function(objects, cb, configObj) {
    errors = 0;
    invalid = [];

    if (!client) {
        if (configObj && typeof configObj === "object")
            client = aerospike.client(configObj);
        else
            client = aerospike.client(config.aerospike);
    }

    if (client.isConnected(false)) {
        execUpdate(objects, cb);
    }
    else {
        client.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }

            execUpdate(objects, cb);
        });
    }
};

function execUpdate(objects, cb) {
    validate(objects, function(err) {
        if (err)
            return cb(err);

        updateObject(objects, function(err) {
            if (err)
                return cb(err);

            if (invalid.length > 0)
                return cb(`Invalid objects: ${invalid.join(",")}`);

            return cb();
        });
    });
}

function validate(objects, cb) {
    if (!Array.isArray(objects))
        return cb("Objects should be provided as an array");

    let valid = config.validObjects;
    for (let i=0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if(valid.indexOf(objects[i]) === -1)
            invalid.push(objects[i]);
    }

    cb();
}

function updateObject(objects, cb) {
    let doc = {};
    let ts = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

    for(let i = 0;i<objects.length;i++)
        doc[objects[i]] = ts;

    let key = new aerospike.Key("namespace", "set", "timestamps");
    client.put(key, doc, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            if (errors > config.errorThreshold) {
                return cb(err);
            }
            else {
                return updateObject(objects, cb);
            }
        }
        else {
            cb();
        }
    });
}

process.on("beforeExit", function() {
    client.close();
});

module.exports = app;
```

But you could say that this is very limited, for example you can only initialize this once, and it's being done in the update method? (Probably cuestionable). Also you don't have any control over the client, which can actually be ok.

Maybe it would be best to pass the client from the requiring code instead, I understand that this may seems like a bad idea but I need to do this in a lot of places, several repos in fact.

My objective would be to have this as a module that I can require and just pass the params I need updated. This repos would be continuously running.

Right now I have implemented this in one repo, I see that the client fails on refresh, maybe while pooling the servers, still need to figure this out.

What I'm not sure is what is the best way to achieve this

Comment: May be you can use a scan and UDF to do this update on a timestamp bin? https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/nodejs/usage/scan/scan_udf.html

Comment: Yes, but what I'm not so sure about is leaving the client connected, ideally I would put and close, the thing is, this detaches it from the event loop, failing the next update when trying to connect again. Maybe this is just the way asd client works and maybe it should just be connected once, not sure about it though

Comment: You don't say how frequently the updates happen so I can't give a recommendation whether to leave the client connected or create a new client each time. But if you do want to go the latter route, you need to call Client#close with releaseEventLoop = false. (See https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/Client.html#close) The, at the end of your program, you need to call Aerospike.releaseEventLoop manually to release the client's event loop resources and to allow the event loop to shut down cleanly. (See https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/module-aerospike.html#.releaseEventLoop)